# Using Dropbox to synchronize files and having them backed up in version control

Tags: git, dropbox

I'm using dropbox for random text notes (org-mode) and dot files that I bootstrap, namely

1. part of my bash initialization
2. emacs configuration
3. vim configuration

Org-mode documentation suggests some backup in case of a mistake in editing folded sections. Makes sense. I also want backups in case I want to back out configuration change.

There are tons of postings on why using git can break in dropbox.

I see a few options:

1. Not use dropbox and use bitbucket to host the files on git. The disadvantage is that when I switch machines, I have to remember to pull any changes, which is not convenient.
2. I can use git via a chron job on one of my machines to backup the files in the dropbox folder and make sure that the git directory is not sync'd by dropbox. The disadvantage would be that this is a little asymetrical in that one machine has git on the dropbox files . However, the history is just for backup purposes rather than collaboration purposes.
3. Not worry about the dropbox issues, as I infrequently commit changes and hardly do any other commands with the git repositories.
4. Maybe a combination of #1 and #2. Occasionally push my changes to remote, having the .git directory not sync'd.

Comment: Nice analysis. Is there a question too?

Comment: Dropbox has backups/version control by itself. Is there some reason why that doesn't do?

Comment: You have to pay $100/year or $10/month for the premium to get backups that last. Looking for recommendations based on experience of others.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dropbox, just not for a full bare Git repo (because of the high number of files to synchronize and the risk for a corrupted repo if even one of those file doesn't get sync properly, as shown in "[Git ref master now empty, how to recover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240479/git-ref-master-now-empty-how-to-recover)").

I prefer to use dropbox in conjunction with a git repo ***bundle*** (ie **one file**):
See "[Git with Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632723/git-with-dropbox/3633346#3633346)" and "[Backup a Local Git Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129286/6309)".
See a detailed analysis in this [blog post](http://batmat.net/blog/post/2011/08/02/Want-to-push-your-git-changes-but-no-connection-on-Holiday-No-worries-git-bundle-is-here).

You can see an example of a [script for that kind of task here](https://gist.github.com/1408924) (example by [shtirlic (Serg Podtynnyi)](https://github.com/shtirlic)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
if __FILE__ == $0
        bundle_name = ARGV[0] if (ARGV[0])
        bundle_name = `pwd`.split('/').last.chomp if bundle_name.nil?
        bundle_name += ".git.bundle"
        puts "Backing up to bundle #{bundle_name}"
        `git bundle create ~/Dropbox/backup/git-repos/#{bundle_name} --all`
end
```

Comment: VonC, in your example, where are you keeping your directory of shared files and your .git dir? If you're just using dropbox to backup a git repo, wouldn't that be easier using the free private repo from bitkeeper? For my notes directory (rather than shared scripts), I don't want to have to remember to sync. Thanks.

Comment: @justingordon: yes, private repos are better. I was only referring in my answer to a solution with Dropbox, should you absolutely want to use *that* service. In that case, backup only *one* file (the bundle), which is safer. However, if you can work directly with private repo, it is easier to do so than using file sync.