# Error deploying to Heroku, failed to run repack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm getting an error when deploying to Heroku after assets are compiled and the app is launched:

```
-----> Compiled slug size: 172.8MB
-----> Launching... done, v274
-----> Deploy hooks scheduled, check output in your logs
       http://mysite.com deployed to Heroku

Auto packing the repository for optimum performance.
error: Could not read ddb3b2358b3ea331cea15b03a8657f929364ec8c
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit c30cd906cd578d9618a4605cefa6e55ac535b42e
error: failed to run repack
```

The deploys appear to be finishing and the newest Ruby code is deployed, but my latest JS changes are not being served. Any thoughts on what might be happening?

Comment: looks like a file size issue (have seen this with git gc before).

Comment: How big is your repo?  Sounds like the deploy on Heroku might be running out of memory.

Comment: tried `git push --force`?

Comment: My Git repo is 45.4MB, currently I don't have problems with deploying to Heroku. Up to my kowledge, the build is conducted by a worker dyno on Heroku. So if Heroku might run out of memory as @CDub assumes, one approach I could think of is to configure the worker dynos from 1X to 2X. 2X dynos have 1GB of RAM while 1X dynos have 512MB (as of 01/2014).

Comment: Something is amiss then, since your repo is ~45MB but the compiled slug size is almost 4x that size...  My experience with Heroku is the most their dynos can support is a slug size of ~90MB, *maybe* 100MB.

Comment: Maybe you give this a look -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/18687206/1609496

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is likely an issue caused by shallow clones. When you don't have a full history, the tree cannot be fully traversed resulting in dangling commits. This often occurs with CI systems where CI does a shallow clone to save on bandwidth and/or latency.

The best course of action to take is to avoid shallow clones.

If a full clone and force push doesn't do the trick, you may need to reset your repo. Resetting your repo re-initializes your app's repo to a bare repo. Your running application will not be affected. There is a utility plugin for resetting your repo on Heroku here:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo

Once installed, run `heroku repo:reset` and then push again.

If the above techniques don't work, please log a support ticket.

Comment: You can also run `git fetch --unshallow` on your CI server before deploying. It helped us on CircleCI.