# How to recover git repository data if system was crashed during switching branches?

Tags: eclipse, git, jboss-developer-studio

I was switching branch in `jboss developer studio (just like eclipse)`. It asked me to commit your changes before switching. I entered `temporary commit` as commit message. Then IDE was doing it's work.

But when IDE was doing all this, system was crashed due to unavailability of electricity.

When power was back I saw much of my files were blank, IDE is not recognizing project as git project, git status is saying `not a git repository`.

How can I recover git repository data if system was crashed during switching branches?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check what's inside the reflog, with :

```
git reflog
```

If you are lucky enough you should find the temporary commit into the reflog list, and then you can restore it from there.

In the case you won't find anything inside the reflog try with this command :

```
git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found
```

The listed commits are copied into `.git/lost-found/commit/`, and non-commit objects are copied into `.git/lost-found/other/` .

Comment: git commands are not working. git is not recognizing that folder as git repository. So those commands will not work.

Comment: @afzalex so it means you have a corrupted repo, take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678853/how-to-fix-corrupted-git-repository maybe it can help .