# find and replace broke .git repo

Tags: git, sed, find, ubuntu-16.04

I had to search and replace few APIs in a big code base. Therefore, I went for stream editor (sed) rather than using IDE

```
find . -not -iwholename '*.git*' -print -exec sed -i 's/<old_pattern>/<new_pattern>/g' {} \;
```

After applying the command git was not able to track (git status, nothing!) my changes anymore. I did exclude '.git' dir but still somehow my local repo was broken. I followed, [How to fix corrupted git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678853/how-to-fix-corrupted-git-repository) but I wonder what broke local repo in the first place when '.git' was not touched?

Comment: You could rerun the command replacing `sed` with `echo sed` to see exactly what commands were run in order to verify that it did what you think it did.

Comment: In particular, you didn't exclude what's *in* the `.git` dir, you just didn't run sed on the directory, um, directly.  Use `-prune` to tell find not to walk into a directory.

Comment: For these kind of operations I use this script, which will only consider tracked files by git: https://github.com/Chiel92/replac