# How can I repair a corrupted Github repository?

Tags: git, github

**Update:** I see my question has been downvoted, almost as if someone thought I was writing about how to repair a corrupted *git* repository.  But my problem is different: I am starting with a blank slate and simply trying to `git clone` a repo from Github.  It seems to me this is a problem distinct from the suggested duplicate question.

If I attempt to `git clone` one of my (previously fine) Github repositories, I get:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 192, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (192/192), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (150/150), done.
remote: fatal: unable to read a66dd5738f00d4549d233ca1e962781d5c81083d
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Again, this used to work fine.  What are my options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix corrupted git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678853/how-to-fix-corrupted-git-repository)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @rsjaffe.  I don't have a local repository to run `git fsck` on.  I'm trying to `clone` my repo in the first place.

Comment: That duplicate question has some advice dealing with remote repositories as well.

Comment: Sounds like you should contact GitHub support, there's not much you can do without a local copy as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I repair a corrupted GitHub repository?

If the repo is purely remote (on GitHub side), there isn't much you can do on your side (except, as commented, to contact GitHub support).

What you can test is: try and [fork that repository](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/), and see if you can clone the fork.

Comment: Thanks.  Just as added information, I forked it—I've never forked it before—and Github said something like: "Are you sure you want to fork this? You've already forked it."  I said, um, yes, thanks, and it forked just fine.  Now I can clone the original repository.  Um.

Comment: @LairdNelson Well... that is a workaround, at least. But I would be interested in what the GitHub support has to say.

Comment: Me too, for sure!  The fact that forking it now allows me to clone the original is a real head-scratcher.