# Git Tag failed with code 128: fatal: unterminated line in .git/packed-refs

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am having an error in SourceTree that says, "Error Encountered: 'git tag' failed with code 128: fatal: unterminated line in .git/packed-refs" If anyone has seen this error and knows a solution I would be grateful.

Comment: I have never seen it, but the obvious thing to do would be to use a text-safe editor (e.g., vim or emacs, not some IDE editor that's going to insert HTML or Microsoft markup crud) on `.git/packed-refs` and correct the file.

Answer (score 26):

Just delete the file `.git/packed-refs`.

Then "refresh" your repo with a `pull` or `fetch`.

> I had the same error `fatal: unterminated line in .git/packed-refs: ...`
>
> (And that file was just lines of:
>
> `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`)
>
> In my case deleting the file worked and I was able to use my repo again.

Failing the above, I would try something like mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46604551/3066295).  The steps are:

- move old git directory
- initialise new repo
- link to old repo (by `remote add origin`)
- get old history (`fetch`)
- force update to old history  (by doing a `reset`)

Comment: this kills all of your local branches too

Answer (score 3):

if did't see `.git/packed-refs` folder from flutter just delete flutter SDK and extract new SDK same folder

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the file .git / packed-refs. from the flutter folder

Download the sdk again from https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows and copy the folder to the flutter location, in this way files were mixed and everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is from a while ago but I ran into this issue today, so just wanted to post what I did to resolve it in case it helps someone. I uninstalled and installed the latest Sourcetree version and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Probably won't be everybody's fix, but I went into the file and looked at it with VS Code text editor and noticed it only had thousands of null characters, so I just deleted all of them an saved. Seemed to do the trick.