# I can't push my update codebase to gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

```
Counting objects: 270, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (247/247), done.
fatal: unable to read 9d7e295637fa81db2e3fdde842f07768a899f1c2
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/HenokTes72/React-Appointment.git'
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Why I cant push my updates to my gitlab repo?

Comment: how big is the size of your code?

Comment: 600Kb  excluding node_modules.

Comment: What is the output of `git fsck --full`?

Comment: Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
broken link from    tree 1da3c29107fbd5bfe33d1f56d4b0fafe78948f64
              to    blob 31b31bb0f473119633904cddb1f4dbd27712997b
broken link from    tree becd9d9d2c1dc7571e44dfdea1a3cae04bf99d4f
              to    blob 9d7e295637fa81db2e3fdde842f07768a899f1c2
missing blob 31a459d5ae8e423d9a82f549829f667fb1b3598d
missing blob 6cfdb44f6c07529cf2551c76e3a0bfbe5aed45e9
dangling blob 6ce17fc1eaa0d847ec482507e125a53309edd07f
missing blob 71950923e4e27748788e3ac21eb4926d09c1ee6d

Answer (score 1):

Your repository is corrupt and missing objects. When you attempt to push it to the remote server, you're unable to find one or more of the objects and therefore the push stalls and the remote server hangs up on you. Even if you pushed all of the objects you had, the remote side would not accept them, because it lacks all the objects.

You should try to find an alternate copy of your repository, which you can try to do by pulling the remote side into a new clone, if there's data there. You can then follow the steps in [this answer to attempt to fix your corrupt repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678853/how-to-fix-corrupted-git-repository).

If there's no other source for your data and you can't manage to recreate the missing blobs, then your repository won't be usable.