# 'git status' failed with code 128: fatal: unable to read

Tags: ios, xcode, git, macos, bitbucket

I want to use Bitbucket for my iOS project but I am getting error after creating repository. Please find error given below:

```
'git status' failed with code 128: fatal: unable to read
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is it "unable to read" or "unable to read tree"?

Comment: its "git status' failed with code 128:'fatal: unable to read ae9f32bf2e19c8ba1823853b90e125241930edda"

Comment: OK, I have edited the answer accordingly. What version of Git are you using?

Comment: git version 2.21.0

Answer (score 4):

[`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) is a local operation, so it should not be impacted by the fact your repository is hosted on Bitbucket.

Try (outside of XCode) a `git status` to see if the issue persists: simply check the rights associated with those files, are they owned by the right user/group on your machine?
Try also to clone again your Bitbucket repository (to a new empty local folder) and see if you can read it (`git status`) and import it in XCode.

If the message is "`unable to read <sha1>`", then the repository might be corrupted, as detailed in:

- "[Git status does not work : unable to find, unable to read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24532416/6309)"
- "[How to fix corrupted Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18678853/6309)"

Check this with [`git fsck --full`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck).