# git -cant pull or commit

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I have a problem committing, and pulling:
In the commit IDE I see:

```
warning not all local changes may be shown due to an error: unable to read tree
```

and only part of my files commits is there, also I cant see diff with the last versions.

when I try to pull/fetch:

```
error: refs/remotes/origin/project-1 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/remotes/origin/project-2 does not point to a valid object!
....
```

and so on

in the end, the error is

```
fatal: pack has 268 unresolved deltas
```

Is there any way for me to fix it without cloning again?

Comment: Run `git fsck` and make sure your repository got not corrupted

Comment: I get a lot of errors and "dangling tree", "missing blob" outputs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, I fixed it by using

```
mv -v .git .git_old &&            # remove old git
git init &&                       # initialise new repo
git remote add origin "${url}" && # link to old repo
git fetch &&                      # get old history
git reset origin/master --mixed   # force update to old history
```

it's from this stack question
[How to fix corrupted git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678853/how-to-fix-corrupted-git-repository)

Comment: but if this git is managed by repo , how to do this?