# Getting errors when linking two golang based repositories and running the golang based server in my local machine

Tags: git, go

I have two repositories `dpay-server` and `dpay-common` with the latter being a common function repository the former can use. The former is a golang server code repository that is used to start the server.

However, whenever I try to start the server, I get the error in the snippet as shown below:

```
starting auth_service...go: github.com/durianpay/dpay-common@v1.20.1-0.20220727064753-c92376be8206: invalid pseudo-version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /Users/pavanvasan/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/ac49d8a5c55a9cf6c728a4698e3370e760c9491837da868854c21d77f2e5dd6f: exit status 128:
    fatal: pack has 5 unresolved deltas
    fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
go: downloading github.com/durianpay/dpay-common v1.20.1-0.20220727064753-c92376be8206
go: github.com/durianpay/dpay-common@v1.20.1-0.20220727064753-c92376be8206: invalid pseudo-version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /Users/pavanvasan/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/ac49d8a5c55a9cf6c728a4698e3370e760c9491837da868854c21d77f2e5dd6f: exit status 128:
    fatal: pack has 5 unresolved deltas
    fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

I tried again by recloning the repos once again and after making minor adjustments like setting up yaml configs, I am still getting the above error.

I followed instructions in I followed the commands in the link [git -cant pull or commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58787277/git-cant-pull-or-commit) But to no avail.

Even setting the following did not work either

```
export GOPRIVATE="github.com/durianpay/dpay-common"
export GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1
```

I am not sure what is going wrong here since the repository is not corrupted. The only way I can link now is by using the `replace` command like:
`replace github.com/durianpay/dpay-common => /Users/user_name/dpay-common`

Can anyone give me an idea as to what is going wrong and how I can solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I got the answer. Looks like I had to remove the `/go/pkg/mod/cache` for the problem to be solved.