# Eclipse E-Git Respository Issue

Tags: eclipse, egit

Unfortunately i deleted GitRepository but after recovery and restore am getting below error and when am trying to open individual xyz.java file it is encrypted or compiled code...
Below is error while am using my eclipse workspace
Please help me with this...

> error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check) error:
>   unable to unpack header of
>   .git/objects/0e/54842123ae27271dd0d4a07fcfa807fbaaf5ec error:
>   0e54842123ae27271dd0d4a07fcfa807fbaaf5ec: object corrupt or missing:
>   .git/objects/0e/54842123ae27271dd0d4a07fcfa807fbaaf5ec error: inflate:
>   data stream error (incorrect header check) error: unable to unpack
>   header of .git/objects/2c/8ba39bb850e154c98ca585f1222532ece0d526
>   error: 2c8ba39bb850e154c98ca585f1222532ece0d526: object corrupt or
>   missing: .git/objects/2c/8ba39bb850e154c98ca585f1222532ece0d526 error:
>   inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check) error: unable to
>   unpack header of
>   .git/objects/3f/3011fd331dcc8df206d4c3b5e472a635bd25b9 error:
>   3f3011fd331dcc8df206d4c3b5e472a635bd25b9: object corrupt or missing:
>   .git/objects/3f/3011fd331dcc8df206d4c3b5e472a635bd25b9 error: inflate:
>   data stream error (incorrect header check) error: unable to unpack
>   header of .git/objects/44/1bdc7472b88ad5530f4523b023636a6528a7d5
>   error: 441bdc7472b88ad5530f4523b023636a6528a7d5: object corrupt or
>   missing: .git/objects/44/1bdc7472b88ad5530f4523b023636a6528a7d5 error:
>   inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check) error: unable to
>   unpack header of
>   .git/objects/6c/1ef2a68972d07f335067029cfb6bc2a05b3e4d error:
>   6c1ef2a68972d07f335067029cfb6bc2a05b3e4d: object corrupt or missing:
>   .git/objects/6c/1ef2a68972d07f335067029cfb6bc2a05b3e4d error: inflate:
>   data stream error (incorrect header check) error: unable to unpack
>   header of .git/objects/8d/e00bfb28ee157da5d8e0886dec578f9b2dca42
>   error: 8de00bfb28ee157da5d8e0886dec578f9b2dca42: object corrupt or
>   missing: .git/objects/8d/e00bfb28ee157da5d8e0886dec578f9b2dca42 error:
>   inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check) error: unable to
>   unpack header of
>   .git/objects/b9/a990efa0a1a4d9d49d4cf01d734f0a72c98dd5 error:
>   b9a990efa0a1a4d9d49d4cf01d734f0a72c98dd5: object corrupt or missing:
>   .git/objects/b9/a990efa0a1a4d9d49d4cf01d734f0a72c98dd5 error: inflate:
>   data stream error (incorrect header check) error: unable to unpack
>   header of .git/objects/bf/47e7cd1006748c5f3b9f6b9c565da65ce54031
>   error: bf47e7cd1006748c5f3b9f6b9c565da65ce54031: object corrupt or
>   missing: .git/objects/bf/47e7cd1006748c5f3b9f6b9c565da65ce54031 error:
>   non-monotonic index
>   .git/objects/pack/pack-ee3246533f85be5e8fddc47432aa74de3eec0205.idx
>   error: packfile
>   .git/objects/pack/pack-ee3246533f85be5e8fddc47432aa74de3eec0205.pack
>   index not opened error: non-monotonic index
>   .git/objects/pack/pack-ee3246533f85be5e8fddc47432aa74de3eec0205.idx
>   error: non-monotonic index
>   .git/objects/pack/pack-ee3246533f85be5e8fddc47432aa74de3eec0205.idx
>   error: non-monotonic index
>   .git/objects/pack/pack-ee3246533f85be5e8fddc47432aa74de3eec0205.idx
>   error: non-monotonic index
>   .git/objects/pack/pack-ee3246533f85be5e8fddc47432aa74de3eec0205.idx
>   error: refs/heads/master: invalid sha1 pointer
>   c99f7be766d4759cb9f39de5b660ff59b0378d28 error: refs/heads/master:
>   invalid reflog entry 4d970fbff7c58fbe10cdce6402ad9a0bb7674534 error:
>   refs/heads/master: invalid reflog entry
>   4d970fbff7c58fbe10cdce6402ad9a0bb7674534 error: refs/heads/master:
>   invalid reflog entry 6f9e26ea26c298395b92a2ae35d3239ece8f3cb0 error:
>   refs/heads/master: invalid reflog entry
>   6f9e26ea26c298395b92a2ae35d3239ece8f3cb0 error: refs/heads/master:
>   invalid reflog entry a7758f5a5dd877d5d2a6c964dba9d499603dacb7 error:
>   refs/heads/master: invalid reflog entry
>   a7758f5a5dd877d5d2a6c964dba9d499603dacb7 error: refs/heads/master:
>   invalid reflog entry c99f7be766d4759cb9f39de5b660ff59b0378d28 error:
>   bad signature 0x65324662 fatal: index file corrupt

Comment: That does sound good: the file `.git/objects/0e/54842123ae27271dd0d4a07fcfa807fbaaf5ec` is missing or is corrupt. Obviously, the recovery was not successful.

Comment: Then how can i recover git object, is there any way to do it, because am unable to read .java file.

Comment: Recover from what? You said _"after recovery and restore"_: What do you mean by that? What exactly did you do? See also [this answer about corrupted Git repository objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18687206/6505250).