# How to solve this, Exception caught during execution of merge command. org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException:

Tags: git, eclipse, exception, egit

I am getting this error **Exception caught during execution of merge command. org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing unknown d695171025c312b964e49bb2fb05e81a2e38dde2** on Eclipse when i am trying to pull. How to solve this? I am suffering 3 days.

[image: Exception]

Comment: Looks like your .git folder is corrupted. It is missing the object with hash d695. Can you check your .git folder for this hash?

Comment: There is no suck object in git folder.

Comment: You can follow steps in this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678853/how-to-fix-corrupted-git-repository to fix your repo

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this by running

```
git fetch && git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a fetch then hard reset didn't work for me.

I backed up the project, blew it away completely, restarted eclipse, made sure it was gone, restarted eclipse again (because it wasn't gone), cloned it, switched to the branch, did a diff/merge between the two folder structures (backup vs. new clone), then was able to check in my changes.