# gitmodulesSymlink: .gitmodules is a symbolic link and github.com

Tags: git, github

How to fix this problem in 2023 when old repos not "manageabel" anymore at github?

Situation:

- local workstation: git version 2.39.2
- local master remote: git version 2.33.0
- github: unknow, but i cannot push or repair anymore to an old repo which seems to be broken because of git version changes (i think). Even symlinks i can not delete and reports a 500 error there (web interface). :-(

local i dont get any error (only with `git fsck`) where .gitmodules is a symlink like:

```
.gitmodules -> one of these (branch based):
.gitmodules_stable
.gitmodules_testing
.gitmodules_unstable
```

Ive tried some very old hints but: No success.
E.g: git-repair and git fsck --full still reporting hundreds of:
`Error in tree [hash]: gitmodulesSymlink: .gitmodules is a symbolic link`

Newer, better hints i dont find out there.

A try to force push to github (symlinks in current branch removed):

- index-pack failed
- remote: error: object [hash]: gitmodulesSymlink: .gitmodules is a symbolic link

I'm out of ideas.

Questions:

- How to repair this localy?
- github i could drop and replace. Or is there another way?

Thank you! :-)

- Tried : [How can I fix a corrupted Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678853/how-can-i-fix-a-corrupted-git-repository)
- Expect: error free repository

**Edit:**
Test rebase using/ edit first 3 commits (.gitmodules not exists at that time. the 3rd. maybe. that i can not checkout :-(

```
git rebase --continue
error: invalid path '.gitmodules'
hint: Could not execute the todo command
```

Other hack to try to solve it using git version 2.11.0 on an old VM:

- git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f .gitmodules'  HEAD

  Stops also:

  Rewrite 33304f788dd7867b37d9dd49d77e093044fae6e2 (3/185) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    error: Invalid path '.gitmodules'
  Could not initialize the index

Comment: This is a `git fsck` error message and every provider is going to disallow that by default.  You need to fix this throughout the entire history and not just in a new commit.

Comment: @bk2204 See my edits.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to correct the errors with the versions available to me.
rewriting the history was only possible with a much older version of git. (git V 1.**).

the complete history was rewritten because almost every commit was affected by errors.

all tags and also some submodule bindings have to be adjusted manually if you have to or want to.
this become nearly a kill for highly used open source programs/libs sharing serveral versions where the developers don't really know which versions/tags are used to bring them back.