# fatal: cannot update the ref 'head': unable to append to '.git/logs/head': invalid argument

Tags: git, github, onedrive

When trying to commit a project to github, the commits fails with an error:
`fatal: cannot update the ref 'head': unable to append to '.git/logs/head': invalid argument`. This is after properly initialising the directory and having a succesfull first push.

##### The important part of the fix: I am using **OneDrive** to keep the files in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other solution:

- do *not* clone anything in a OneDrive-sync'ed folder (as seen here)
- push / pull as expected from a normal regular folder
- create at any time a [`git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309): it produces *one* file (representing the full repository content), see [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851166/6309).

You can store one file in a backup drive.

Answer (score 5):

You should never use a cloud syncing service such as OneDrive to store a Git repository.  There are a couple reasons for this:

- First, cloud syncing services sync file by file, whereas Git relies on the entire repository being in a single state, so using these services can cause corruption due to leaving the repository in an inconsistent state.  People have been known to lose data from doing this.
- Git requires a file system that provides POSIX semantics, including the ability to append to files atomically.  This is generally possible with a normal Windows file system, but many cloud syncing services use custom file systems that don't provide these abilities, so Git just won't work with them.

In this case, you're seeing the latter problem.

The best way to sync a repository across machines is just to push and pull to a remote, like GitHub.  You can also use `git bundle` to transfer a bundle file using whatever method you like.  Your final option is to sync between machines using `rsync -a --delete-after` (preferably using SSH), but you must make sure that the repository is completely idle when you're doing that, which also means that things like `git gc` and editor integrations aren't running.  If it isn't, you can end up with corruption.

Answer (score 3):

### **The solution:**

Start **OneDrive** if it has not yet been started. After this you should be able to push succesfully

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, I was storing the repo under Dropbox.